# Tricky Excel Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, finance

Trying to build a screening tool in excel. I am using three different variables to produce a yes or no in the final cell.

The first two variables are Assets and Tier 1 capital. These are simple greater than tests. The third is where I am stuck as I do not have an idea of which formula supports this. OECD country is a yes, no or NA.

I have the country of incorporation and a list of the 25+ OECD countries and am using a match formula to tie together.

At this point I am using =if statements to describe if the row meets the min. asset and tier one capital requirements then it would equal 1 if not zero. Then add these together to have a final column that if it equals 2 then "yes", if does not equal 2 then "no." I am trying to build an if statement, or something similar, that would allow 3 if conditions. "Yes", "No', "NA". if yes then 1 if no than 0, if NA ignore test.

The below right are the inputs of the model and the qualified lender column is the output. There is a lot here and welcome suggestions on making this question better.

```
Qualified Lender?       Screening Criteria      Amount ($)
No                      Assets ($MM)                    $1
No                      Capital and Surplus ($MM)       $1
No                      OECD                           Yes
No                      Currency                   USD $MM
No              
No                  
Yes
```

Please follow link below for full spreadsheet. 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2fOEGxoV2UNMzFxREtTd3l5MkE

Comment: It's hard to figure out the exact rules from your verbal description, and the example doesn't seem to illustrate the logic.  Can you add a table that shows examples of the values in the three source variables and the expected output?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but it sounds like some combination of AND and OR might fit the bill.

Comment: The question is interesting, but is lacking a bit of detail. What do your current formulas look like?

Comment: See the update above, tried to avoid showing how the sausage is made.

Comment: I see you marked this as answered, did the nested IF statement work? I ended up being too busy with work to take a closer look like I said I would. Let me know if you're still having trouble with the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a nested `IF` statement to get the three conditions you require.

For example:

`=IF(A1="Yes",1,IF(A1="No",0,"-1"))`

This will result in:

`Yes` when `A1` equals `1`.
`No` when `A1` equals `0`.
`N/A` when `A1` equals `-1`.

[Example Sheet to show how the trinary IF statement works](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B8DI6i_0b0tNd1NBOF8zZzBCWDQ&usp=sharing)

Comment: I completed the rest of the Spreadsheet as I interpreted your question, but won't post it until you clarify if the 3-way IF statement was all you needed or not.

Comment: this is close to what I am looking for. But, I would like NA to omit that condition. We are looking for lenders and sometime a requirement is they be from a particular country. But in other cases it doesn't matter. In the cases it doesn't matter I want the output to reflect that.

Comment: I have a spreadsheet that works how I think you want it. However the logic  uses a couple different formulas and will probably be quite confusing to explain without an example sheet. I'll email it home and then think about how I can expand it into an answer for you.

Comment: @SJSU2013 I've added a link with how I would work out the values.

Comment: I added a link of my full spreadsheet. Hopefully that better explains what I am trying to achieve.